# How events are generated in Java?

Tags: java, swing, events

First of all I am not asking about Event **Handling**. I know handling is implemented using the Observer pattern.

Let me take a small example. Suppose I have a Jbutton on a JFrame. I click on top of this button. 
Now how does the button know that I have clicked it?

1) Is there any java thread waiting for the click? If so from where does this code come from (wait till I get clicked part)? Then Does each and every swing component is waiting for events on top of threads? I assume this is a very expensive task.

2) If not, how does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observer pattern is used throughout the entire stack:

1. The user releases the mouse button
2. The mouse sends a message to the CPU, which triggers a hardware interrupt
3. The operating system's interrupt handler realizes that the mouse has not been moved since the button was pressed, i.e. that a mouse click occured. It identifies the window at the mouse position, and the application responsible for that window, and puts a mouse-clicked message into the application's event queue
4. Our Swing application's "event dispatch thread" runs a loop of the form:

   ```
   while (!shutdownRequested) {
       Event e = retrieveEventFromEventQueue(); // for instance our mouse clicked event
       handleEvent(e);
   }
   ```

   In AWT / Swing, there is single thread executing that code. The first call will block until a new event becomes available, and handleEvent() will call the listeners for this event. That is, a single thread performs all UI updates (which is why long-running tasks should not be done in event listeners, as this freezes the ui), and is sleeping if the user does not interact with the application.

Comment: i exactly wanted an answer like this

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any java thread waiting for the click?

Yes, `java.awt.EventDispatchThread`. Here a quote from [the event dispatch thread section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) of the java tutorial :

> Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event
>   dispatch thread. Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on
>   this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are
>   not "thread safe": invoking them from multiple threads risks thread
>   interference or memory consistency errors. Some Swing component
>   methods are labelled "thread safe" in the API specification; these can
>   be safely invoked from any thread. All other Swing component methods
>   must be invoked from the event dispatch thread. Programs that ignore
>   this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to
>   unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.

To answer your next question,

> If so from where does this code come from (wait till I get clicked
>   part)?

The `EventDispatchThread` starts a *permanent* event pump with a call to `pumpEvents(Conditional)` in its `run` method.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        pumpEvents(new Conditional() {
            public boolean evaluate() {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } finally {
        getEventQueue().detachDispatchThread(this);
    }
}
```

Any event handlers can choose to block this event pump at any time, but should start a new pump (not a new EDT) by again calling `pumpEvents(Conditional)`. This secondary event pump will exit automatically as soon as the `Conditional` evaluate to `false` and an additional `Event` is pumped an dispatched.

The pump event will call `AWTEvent#getNextEvent` which will retrieve event from the event queue.

> Then Does each and every swing component is waiting for events on top
>   of threads? I assume this is a very expensive task.

Again, the java tutorial answer this

> It's useful to think of the code running on the event dispatch thread
>   as a series of short tasks. Most tasks are invocations of
>   event-handling methods, such as ActionListener.actionPerformed. Other
>   tasks can be scheduled by application code, using invokeLater or
>   invokeAndWait. Tasks on the event dispatch thread must finish quickly;
>   if they don't, unhandled events back up and the user interface becomes
>   unresponsive.

Events are enqueued in a platform-independent class `java.awt.EventQueue`. Events are stored in queue given a priority, one queue is created for each priority.

```
private static final int LOW_PRIORITY = 0;
private static final int NORM_PRIORITY = 1;
private static final int HIGH_PRIORITY = 2;
private static final int ULTIMATE_PRIORITY = 3;
```

> Events are pulled off the EventQueue starting with the Queue of
>   highest priority. We progress in decreasing order across all Queues.

Note that some events commonly called are cached for better performance such as `PaintEvent.Paint`, `PaintEvent.UPDATE`, `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED`, `MouveSevent.MOUSE_DRAGGED`.

This is not as expensive as you think.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any java thread waiting for the click?

Yes, it's called the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT).

Since all components in Swing are lightweight, meaning just a nice animation and nothing more, it is really the top-level component, say, the `JFrame` that keeps track of mouse clicks, and passes them up to the component on that pixel.

Comment: All that talk about design-patterns in the world and `MouseEvent` knows what the `JFrame` does ;)